# How to design In App Purchase of reader app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am developing a reader app. Now, I am trying to use IAP to implement the payment in the app. I've read In-App Purchase Programming Guide and some tutorials. Now I still have some questions not clear.

1) we must use IAP for the payment in this case? no others?

2) If using IAP, we need to add all books to iTunes Connect's product list? If there are thousands of books, we need to add everyone manually?

3) In order to cooperate with IAP, what should my server side to do?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) we must use IAP for the payment in this case? no others?

if you plan to sell books on your app you have to use IAP or Apple will reject your app, there are no others options

> 2) If using IAP, we need to add all books to iTunes Connect's product list? If there are thousands of books, we need to add everyone manually?

yes, you have to add all the books to iTunes Connnect, one by one

Comment: thanks for your response. Besides these two questions, i wonder what should my server side to do to cooperate with the itunes connect for IAP?

Comment: that depends on your particular case, I have developed a similar app a time ago and I add the purchased ids to the user profile, and off course, the books are stored in my server ;-)